How can I create instances of habits for the next 30 days, so that the habit instances do not need to be created to infinity?
I'm currently developing a habit tracker application using MongoDB and Next.js, and I'm facing an issue with creating instances of habits for users. Here’s a brief overview of my current setup:
I have three collections in my MongoDB database:
Users: Contains user information.
Habits: Contains details about habits such as habit name, description, frequency (daily or specific days of the week), and time.
HabitInstances: Contains instances of habits for specific dates, with fields for user ID, habit ID, date, and status (completed or not).
When a user adds a new habit, it is saved in the Habits collection. Here is an example of a habit:

The challenge I'm facing is efficiently generating instances of these habits for the next 30 days without creating them indefinitely. For instance, if a user wants to repeat a habit every Monday, Tuesday, and Wednesday, I need to create instances for the next 30 days so that when the user checks the app, they can see their habits scheduled for those specific days.
Creating these instances indefinitely would be inefficient and could lead to performance issues, especially with many users.
Could anyone provide a detailed explanation or example of how to generate these habit instances for the next 30 days based on the habit's frequency? Any guidance on implementing this in MongoDB and Next.js would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Are these habits bad or good?

@AlexBlex they are good habits

Than it would be a right thing to do to create them indefinitely and keep forever. But jokes apart, what's the question? You came up with a schema design with 3 entities - users, habits, and the lookup "instances" between them. If it is what you need there is no way around. Delete the past instances when you don't need them maybe? Regarding the performance - you might be surprised how fast mongo can be. Prove it is a problem before fixing it. Premature optimisation is a bad habit.

you can add a function that run every day (by cron) and clear the oldest instances
